# When bind view model attribute to a input textbox, it crashes in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

This is the error message when IE8 crashes.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x05A99E34 (mshtml.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000003C.
```

the following works.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: searchResults">
    <tr><td data-bind="text: orgName"></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

but the following crash on IE8 (works on IE10, FF and Chrome).

`orgName` is just a string set in the `vm.searchStakeholder`.

Here's more about the view model.

```
var Stakeholder = (function () {
    function Stakeholder(orgName) {
        this.orgName = ko.observable(orgName);
    };
    return Stakeholder;
})();

var vm = new function () {
    var self = this;
    self.searchResults = ko.observableArray();

    self.searchStakeholder = function (){
        $.ajax({
             type:'get',
             dataType: 'json',
             url: 'the-url',
             contentType: 'application/json',
             success: function(json){
                 for(var i = 0; i < json.SearchResults.length; i++) {
                     var x = json.SearchResults[i];
                     self.searchResults.push(new Stakeholder(x.orgName));
                 }
             }
        });            
    };

});


ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#divMyApp')[0]);
```

Comment: Just for my understanding, why the second level of redundancy when creating a stakeholder?  You are declaring it as a variable that is equal to a function of a function of the same name.  Also, is there any reason you name your property the same as the object being passed in?  I don't know about that error specifically but it looks like IE8 could potentially interpret that as a circular reference of some sort.

Comment: I want to create a Stakeholder class that has well defined properties and constructor. It does sound like circular reference issue but it doesn't crash on FF or Chrome.

Comment: You realize that the `text` binding on the `td` will overwrite the entire contents of the `td` right? If you remove that binding do you get the error?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, I did see that, but I also tried to move the input box to its own TD but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting some results back of type Stakeholder and storing them in searchResults -

```
<table data-bind="with: searchResults">
    <th><tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Org Name</td>
    </tr></th>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: stakeholder">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: orgName" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Works in IE8.  But since your searchResults is a KO.observableArray() I assume that you need to foreach your searchResults, but without a better picture of what you are doing it's hard to tell, here that is anyway.

```
<table>
    <th><tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Org Name</td>
    </tr></th>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: searchResults">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: orgName" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also can't tell what orgName is or how it is being passed to the constructor of the Stakeholder, if it is a KO.observable then remove it as a parameter and use orgName(), if it is a parameter being passed in then move it up to the parent function and rename it to ensure it isn't a circular reference.

```
var Stakeholder = (function (organizationName) {
    var self = this;
    function Stakeholder() {
        this.orgName = ko.observable(self.organizationName);
    };
    return Stakeholder;
})();
```

Last, not sure what the 'blah' element is at the bottom, maybe just a copy pasta typo?

Comment: the blah is a DOM element that contains other elements for binding.

Comment: I also added more code to show how I add Stakeholder to the array.

Comment: Are you planning to send orgName back to the database or just have it as a property that is there?

Comment: I need to sent it back to DB after user updates, that's why I have it setup as a observable.